# list or name of all opened gnome terminals in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm on Oracle Linux. I have a shell script that does the following:

```
#some stuff happening here

gnome-terminal --title='my application' -x /path/my_application -param val

#some more stuff
```

Now, it's quite possible that the script will be executed multiple times.  However, I only want `my_application` to be started if it's not already running.  I found the following code that does that:

```
ps cax | grep my_application > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "My application already running."
else
    gnome-terminal --title='my application' -x /path/my_application -param val
fi
```

This works fine.  Here's where I have a problem. I have a second shell script. It also runs `my_application`, but with different parameters. It's possible that both scripts be executed together. If that happens, there must be two instances of `my_application` running, since they have different parameters.  My idea was to give each gnome-terminal a different title, then check if a gnome-terminal with that title already exists before starting `my_application`.

That said, I may be going at this completely wrong, so any suggestions are welcome.

In summary, I have two scripts that both start the same application, but with different parameters. Both scripts may be executed together and multiple times each.  If a given script started the application, it must not start the application again when that script is executed again (assuming said application is still running).  However, one script starting the application must not prevent the other script from starting the same application.

Answer (score 2):

Script 1:

```
CMD="gnome-terminal --title='my application' -x /path/my_application -param val"

flock -n /var/lock/mylock1 $CMD || echo "My application already running."
```

Script 2:

```
CMD="gnome-terminal --title='my application' -x /path/my_application -param val"

flock -n /var/lock/mylock2 $CMD || echo "My application already running."
```

Comment: I didn't know about flock, so thanks for that.  However, that specific solution doesn't work.  Instead, it should be something like: gnome-terminal --title='my application' -x flock -n /var/lock/mylock1 /path/my_application -param val